# Python 3.7 Scapy install failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scapy

I tried to install Scapy for Python 3.7. I got the following error message which I can not explain.

Used commands: pip install scapy

```
   C:\Users\Frank>Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a7qfqmx_\\scapy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-89rwlqnn\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7qfqmx_\scapy\Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Frank\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a7qfqmx_\\scapy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
    'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-89rwlqnn\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Frank\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a7qfqmx_\scapy\
```

Has anyone of you had a similar problem and found a suitable solution?

Answer (score 4):

**Update: Python 3.7 is supported since Scapy 2.4.2+**

The PyPi release does not support Python 3.7

You need to use the development version, over here: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/archive/master.zip

Unzip it and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Thank´s ! The help´s me!